# Cannot grab the first id value from the table to show in the selection box

Tags: php, sql, select

I have a problem to show first id value to show in the select option box, it can show me other id value, just cannot show me the first id value from the table. Below is my coding:

```html
<select onchange="getComboA(this)" class="form-control blank" id="parentid" name="parentid" title="parentid">
   <!-- <option selected disabled>Please Select</option>-->
    <!--Make this selected by default-->
    <option selected value="0">New Category</option
    <?php

    $sql_incharge = 'select * from filing_code_management where status=1 order by id';
    $arr_incharge = db_conn_select($sql_incharge);

    foreach ($arr_incharge as $rs_incharge) {
        $folder_location      = $rs_incharge['folder_location'];
        $function_code_select = $rs_incharge['function_code'];
        $function_name_select = $rs_incharge['function_name'];
        $activity_code_select = $rs_incharge['activity_code'];
        $activity_name_select = $rs_incharge['activity_name'];
        $name_select = $rs_incharge['name'];
        $id_select            = $rs_incharge['id'];
        $category_id          = $rs_incharge['category_id']; // get category_id here
        // save the data here↓↓ in data attributes 
        echo "<option value='{$id_select}' data-cat_id='{$category_id}'>{$name_select}</option>";

        }

        ?></select>
```

Below is my table value picture, my id 1 value is **100 PENTADBIRAN**, but the selection box show me start from id 2 value:

[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdtRW.png)

Below is my output to show no first id value in the selection box, the id is start from id 2 not start from id 1:

[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvalN.png)

What I have tried:

I have tried paste this code select * from filing_code_management where id=1  in the sql server to check. It can show me id 1 value in the sql server. But I don't know why if I using this code in my coding, it cannot work.

Hope someone can guide me which part I am getting wrong and can show me the first id value in the selection box.

Comment: Does `100 PENTADBIRAN` is showing somewhere in your selectbox ? Try `ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: trying counting the return value if its the same as the count in SQL Server. if its the same, it is due to the sorting

Comment: No showing I using ORDER BY id ASC, stil same result

Comment: Your sql statement contains 'where status=1 order by id' so what is the 'status' or id=1. If the status is not 1 then it will not be included in the returned results.

Comment: Make sure id is set as INT with no space and It has a unique value

Comment: @jeff status is 1 , it is in the screenshots of the question

Comment: @Ajith Make sure id is set as INT

Comment: @SoonWinner Can you tell me the result of `print_r($arr_incharge)` just above the foreach loop , and tell me where `100 PENTADBIRAN` value exist in the print_r

Comment: @Ajith how to see the print_r($arr_incharge) result? I have paste this code above the foreach loop

Comment: @Ajith Thanks your suggestion. After put print_r($arr_incharge) above the foreach loop, it can show the first id value

Comment: Can you tell me why after add print_r($arr_incharge) will show the first id value?

Comment: @SoonWinner  I didnt get you, Did you get the print_r  with correct values ? Screenshot Please

Comment: @Ajith I get the print_r with correct values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an html issue. The first selected option

```
<option selected value="0">New Category</option
```

Is missing the closing ">". As such the first element is being rendered as a part of the HTML. When the first result from your query is rendered, it finally closes this selected option.

You may close it as shown below

```
<option selected value="0">New Category</option>
```